# Populaing a query in Typeorm

Tags: sql, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

Can anyone help me to know how to populate a query in typeorm. Like I have this entity

```
@Entity('users')
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @Column()
  userName : string;
  
  @Column()
  email : string;

  @OneToMany(() => UserFollowing, (userFollowing) => userFollowing.followee)
  followers: User[];

  @OneToMany(() => UserFollowing, (userFollowing) => userFollowing.follower)
  followees: User[];
}

@Entity('user_followings')
export class UserFollowing extends FakeBaseEntity {
  @JoinColumn({ name : 'follower_id' })
  @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.followees)
  follower : User;

  @JoinColumn({ name : 'followee_id' })
  @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.followers)
  followee : User;
}
```

Now to get all the `followers` and `followees` of a particular `userid`

Here are my two approaches : both giving same output

```
const info = await this.userRepo
      .createQueryBuilder('userFollowing')
      .select()
      .leftJoinAndSelect('userFollowing.followers','followers')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('userFollowing.followees', 'followees')
      .where('userFollowing.id = :userid', { userid })
      .getMany()

return info;
------------------------------------------------------------
const info = this.userRepo.find({
      where: {
        id : userid,
      },
      relations: ["followers", "followees"],
    })
return info;
```

output I am recieving : and I want all the info about followers and followees

```json
{
    "id": "e8651d4f-3c7b-4f5a-8205-7370b107d98c",
    "userName": "something",
    "email" : "something@gmail.com",
    "followers": [
      {
        "id": "f54b8574-10ea-4133-85bd-5f8fcda4eeb9",
        "createdAt": "2021-08-12T03:58:39.198Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-08-12T03:58:39.198Z"
      }
    ],
    "followees": [
      {
        "id": "eb2cb728-a1c0-4bea-9230-712827c714c7",
        "createdAt": "2021-08-12T03:59:32.260Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-08-12T03:59:32.260Z"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, then what you are looking for is to get the data of followers and followees as well.

You can easily achieve this with the `find` function.

This is how your query should look:

```
const info = this.userRepo.find({
  where: {
    id : userid,
  },
  relations: ["followers", "followees", "followers.follower", "followees.followee"],
})
```

As you can see, I have passed two more string values in the `relations`.
Using this, it will load the sub-relations as well (stated in the [TypeORM Find Options](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/find-options#basic-options)).

You can achieve the same using query builder as well by adding more `.leftJoinAndSelect` method chain.

External Links:

- [TypeORM Find Options](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/find-options#basic-options)

Comment: I already did this. It's not working. Giving me an empty array of followers and followees.

Comment: Oh my bad. At first all the entries in the `user_following` table `follower_id` and `followee_id` got nulled don't kknow how. But yeah its working.

Comment: @BhargavGohil Glad to hear that it's working. Also, it would be awesome if you could accept it as the best answer. :)